# multi-dimension array to image

Tags: c, image, multidimensional-array

if i had a 5 X 5 multidimensional-array, where all values would be ether 0 or 1, would there be a way to generate a 5 X 5 pixel image where 1 was black and 0 was white?

i would like to do this in c.

the output image type would not matter.

--Thanks

chad

Comment: *the output image type would not matter* - Are you *sure* about that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: mark, a script is going to call this application and it could convert the image to whatever more easily than the c application could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is 5x5 then it is 2-dimensional which is more specific than calling it multi-dimensional.

Read up on the pbm or the pgm image formats. They are very easy to use and they are easily output by your program.

Comment: And the netpbm library is fairly easy to use.

Comment: thanks i found this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format
so i am going to try to play around with that

Answer (score 0):

If the output type does not matter, just generate it in raw format, for each `1` write three bytes `255` to the output (binary) file, for each `0` write three `0` bytes.